loading prepopulated sqlite database is slow in react native
I have prepopulated database like a table with list of 100k rows. the data is static, it wont change. I am trying to load the data first then, enable search, to search words within the table. The issue I am facing is the data takes so long to load and when i search in the autocomplete, for first few seconds it doesn't show any data. So is there anyway in react native to load the data first and either save it locally so that it doesnt have to try to access from the database.
Here is my code to get the data from the database,
const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
name: 'DictionaryG.db',
createFromLocation: '~DictionaryG.db',
location: 'Library',
});

export const executeSqlQuery = query => {
var words= [];

db.transaction(tx => {
tx.executeSql(query, [], (tx, results) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
    words.push(results.rows.item(i));
  }
  return words;
 });
 });
return words;
};

here is the code to get the words
const MainHome = () => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const loadData = useCallback(() => {
const query = 'SELECT Word,Id FROM EnglishWords LIMIT 5';
const nouns = executeSqlQuery(query);
console.log('words: ', nouns);
if (nouns.length) {
  setItems(nouns);
 }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 loadData();
}, [loadData]);

console.log('English words', items);
 return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <Text>Main Home Screen </Text>
  {items.map(item => {
    return (
      <View key={item.Id}>
        <Text> {item.Word}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  })}
</View>
 );
};

Console log results is showing Empty:

For many reasons, it is better to create an API that connects to your database and sends the data to your mobile app, instead of having the app connect directly to your production database. Some of the reasons are:
1. Performance
All heavy work will be done on the back-end of your server, which makes the app usability more smooth. Since the end-user can have from a 1GB's of ram cellphone, to a 16GB's one, it is not advised to have the app do all front-end and heavy back-end work.
2. Scalability
If you mess something up, and need to update your app, if the app is on the store, it might take 2 business days for your update to be released (Android is generally faster, but IOS usually takes more than 1 day).
That's not a problem if you use an API, you can just change the code on your server and it changes everywhere.
3. Security
The user can easily use some network monitoring tools to see what your app is sending to your back-end, which in this case, would include your database's username and password. And, you would need to have your database open to every IP address that would use your app, so that would cause a lot of problems with security.
And, many other reasons why it is a bad idea to use native SQL in your app.
You can create an API easy with fastApi, flask, and other frameworks.
But, if you really need to use SQL in your app, you can try op-sqlite, which is a library that intends to be faster.
[EDIT]
I just saw it is a local database, so, the security part might not apply to your use-case.
[EDIT 2]
You actually need the data offline, and have quite a lot of rows.
I went after some databases that promise to be faster than SQLite, and found lokijs. The only problem is that it hasn't been updated in 5 years.
If that doesn't help, you could try to improve the performance, by:

Having all the data already saved how you need it to be.
Using SQLite indexes


the only reason I am using the sqlite is the data is available offline.

Oh, makes sense now. I'm updating my answer then

@kiflay done. Hope it helps

Thanks @William
How could i do 1. which is Having all the data already saved. I tried to query all the data globally and try to query it, it still seems very slow.
